# How to build AR model by acf and pacf

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, acf-pacf

I want to do an estimation by "garchFit" function in R. In the lecture, we are told that we can first plot acf and pacf and decide which formula in "garchFit" function we will use. However, I found the pattern of pacf is strange. Can anyone tell me how to write the "garchFit" function based on this graph?
[image]

Comment: Autoregression and GARCH are two different things. Why do you want to fit an autoregression using `garchFit` rather than `ar`?

Comment: If you find this pattern strange, I would suggest that you plot the ACF and PACF of a simulated iid normal white noise of similar sample size a few times. You will find that it frequently looks just like this, and that it's not so much a "pattern" as it is just noise.

Comment: My goal is to do a Monte Carlo simulation approach based on copula theory. I want to do an estimation by GARCH but I do not know how to fill in the numbers of formula in GRACH. So I tried to do acf and pacf. But I trapped in the patterns of the graph. Would you give me some advice? THANKS.